# EF 4.3 relationships not right

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ObjectB Objectb {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid ObjectAId {get; set;}
    public virtual ObjectA ObjectA {get; set;}
}
```

I'm having no luck getting the relationships correct.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.ObjectB)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Two relationships are created:

1. Object.ObjectA/ObjectA.Id
2. ObjectA.Id/ObjectB.Id

How do I get EF to stop creating relationship #2? It's not correct and not what I want.

Wrong:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().HasRequired(x => x.Objectb).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.ObjectA);

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ObjectBs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectBs_ObjectAs_Id] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjectAs] ([Id])
    GO
```

Almost right:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().HasOptional(x => x.Objectb).WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.ObjectA);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ObjectBs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectBs_ObjectAs_ObjectA_Id] FOREIGN KEY([ObjectA_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjectAs] ([Id])
GO
```

An additional column is added, so I end up with ObjectAId and ObjectA_Id in ObjectB.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().HasOptional(x => x.Objectb).WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.ObjectA).Map(x => x.MapKey("ObjectAId"));
```

Throws an exception: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'ObjectAId' was already defined.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the foreign key property from `ObjectB`:

```cs
public class ObjectA
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ObjectB Objectb {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ObjectA ObjectA {get; set;}
}
```

And use this mapping with Fluent API:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.ObjectB)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(b => b.ObjectA)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The reason why you need to remove the foreign property is that EF does not support One-to-One Foreign Key Associations, but only [One-to-One Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx).

If you want a One-to-One Foreign Key Association where the dependent has a foreign key as a unique key being different from the primary key [there is only a workaround](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) to map your model as a one-to-many relationship without a navigation property on the many side of the relationship and a unique constraint in the database, like so:

```cs
public class ObjectA
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid ObjectAId {get; set;}
    public virtual ObjectA ObjectA {get; set;}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectB>()
    .HasRequired(b => b.ObjectA)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.ObjectAId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was hoping to avoid removing the foreign key because it's used. I can refactor that code.

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally worked after removing the foreign key property as suggested by Slauma.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.ObjectB)
    .WithRequired(x => x.ObjectA)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("ObjectAId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I had to map the property otherwise the foreign key was created on the primary keys.

Comment: This is really bother me. I would like to map "ObjectAId" in a property because I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.ObjectB)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ObjectAId);
```

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698